# How to add a property to a CSS class using typescript in Angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript

i have a css class in global.scss

```
.grecaptcha-badge {
}
```

i want to add a CSS property to this class from typescript

```
visibility: hidden
```

the div doesn't actually exist in my HTML file because it's the google Recaptcha V3 API div so i cannot use NgClss or NgStyle properties, is there any way to add it dynamically from typescript ?

Comment: Are you sure you cannot use `NgStyle`? Have you tried it? And please, show the HTML code!

Comment: did you try ng-deep ?

Comment: you cannot modify css files via typescript on runtime